# DATE_FORMAT() in MySQL return unexpected string in side stored procedure

Tags: mysql, date-format

I am facing an issue with `date_format()` in a stored procedure. When I am trying to format a `datetime` to string from outside the stored procedure, it works perfectly - as shown here:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2021-04-07 23:59:59.999999', "%d %b %Y");
```

Output is `07 Apr 2021`, which expected.

But inside the stored procedure, it returns `08 Apr 2021`. I think the issue is with `.999999` part. If I remove that then `date_format()` return `07 Apr 2021`. How can I solve it?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `App_Date_Format`(IN  pDateTime DATETIME)
BEGIN
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(pDateTime, "%d %b %Y");
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**NB**: this is a part of my full stored procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define the parameter as `DATETIME`, so provided value is rounded. Define it as `DATETIME(6)`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `App_Date_Format`(IN  pDateTime DATETIME(6))
BEGIN
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(pDateTime, "%d %b %Y");
END
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d1017437fa575d42098b6f18014d9f0f

Comment: thanks for your answer, but ```DATETIME(6)``` neglects the ```.999999``` inside SP. I also need that part. there is some query from the table depending on that datetime value. Is it possible?

Comment: *DATETIME(6) neglects the .999999 inside SP* Provided fiddle demonstrates that it is taken into account, but you insist that it is neglected nevertheless? Did you follow the link at all?

Comment: sorry, I am not an expert in using the fiddle. Yes, it considers the whole value for the query. thanks